# Spring Integration : MQSeries Message Driven Adapter Not Working

Tags: spring, spring-integration, message-queue, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am able to successfully integrate ActiveMQ(in bound message driven channel) and Kafka (as outbound channel). It working fine.

Now, since Both ActiveMQ and MQ Series are JMS compliant, i thought transition would be easier.  But, its throwing below error :

```
Setup of JMS Message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue://abcd' - trying to recover - Cause: JMSQ1112: The operation for a domain specific object was not valid. The operation 'createConsumer' is not valid for type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue'
```

My spring integration config looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd">

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="requestChannelAdapter" channel="requestChannel" 
    container="requestListenerContainer" error-channel=""/>


    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
        auto-startup="true" sync="true" channel="inputToKafka" topic="test">
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

And my respective code looks like below:

```
public MQQueueConnectionFactory jmsConnectionfactory() {

        MQQueueConnectionFactory jmsFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        jmsFactory.setHostName(hostname);
        jmsFactory.setPort(1444);
        jmsFactory.setQueueManager(//valid queue manager);
        jmsFactory.setChannel(//valid channel name);
        jmsFactory.setTransportType(1);
        jmsFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(// valid suite);
        return jmsFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer requestListenerContainer() {

        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionfactory());
        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
        container.setDestination(helloJMSQueue());
        return container;
    }


    @Bean
    public Queue helloJMSQueue() {
        return new MQQueue(HELLO_QUEUE);
    }
```

Why I am getting this error ? I saw some posts that it is due to pubLocal value not available in jmsTemplate w.r.t MQQueue but that was dated back to 2005 and i noticed the change has been released.

Answer (score 1):

Use just `container.setDestinationName(HELLO_QUEUE)` instead and let the container to resolve it properly over `Session`.